# How to rotate Tomcat Log file when it reached certain limit

Tags: tomcat

In Windows you can go to go to Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat6.0\bin and run tomcat6w.exe as administrator Under the Java tab, in the Java Options section add the following:  -Djava.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=25000000  This will set the default stdout.log file to 25MBs before it rotates to a new log file.
even if i configured log file is not rotating size is reached to limit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `$tomcat/logs/catalina.out` cannot be logrotated but `$tomcat/logs/mywebapp.log` files are possible in Tomcat's default JULI(JavaUtilLogInterface) implementation.

Add `mywebapp/WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties` file to webapps.

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler

## limit=KB of file, count=number of files to be kept    
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINE
#org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
#org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = mywebapp.
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = ${catalina.base}/logs/mywebapp.%g.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 2000000 
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 5
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```